# How to read xml file set the content as Transform Message 's payload in Mulesoft (Dataweave)

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I need to read the content of XML file and set it as payload via Transform Message Component
I did it as below, but got Error as below

Dataweave Script

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
Mule::p('file::src/test/resources/inbound.xml')
```

Error

```
""Trying to output non-whitespace characters outside main element tree (in prolog or epilog), while writing Xml at ." evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
Mule::p('file::src/test/resources/inbound.xml')"."
```

I thoguht if i set output as java instead of xml, it could get rid of error. but the output type will be java, i need convert it into xml by another extra step. I am new bee in mulesoft. any idea or hints are appreicated.

Answer (score 1):

Using the p() function makes no sense at all. That function is for reading the values of properties defined in the Mule application (see https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/latest/configuring-properties) which is a different use case.

You can use use the [readUrl() function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/latest/dw-core-functions-readurl) to read the contents of a file. However you should be aware of some caveats. You should not reference anything in the source directories of your project. That may work during development but the src directory won't even exist when deploying to a standalone Mule server. And don't use file: URLs because Mule applications get packaged into JAR files.

Instead use the `classpath:` schema and reference the file relative to the `resource` directory.

Example:

```
readUrl("classpath://inbound.xml", "application/xml")
```

Comment: yes, This way works, btw, i also tried another approach, I just set breakpoint at transform message, and run program in debug mode, when it hits break point, just i tried to update payload value with copied content of XML file , but it seems does not work ...

Comment: Even if changing a payload in the debugger worked, how that would be helpful if you what you are trying to do -I assume- is to mock a test case that should execute automatically? I'm assuming it is a test case because is a test resource.